# using some sort of basic word art in android

Tags: android, text, colors

I'm writing an app that invoves the user writing some sort of greeting text ("happy holidays" or the sort). I'd like to give the user as much freedom as possible in choosing the font and color of the text. So far what I've come up with is assigning specific buttons with specific text colors - i.e. button for green text with red line, button with yellow text and blue background, etc.
Is there a more general way to do this? i.e. some kind of built - in color pallett/font selection screen that can pop up for the user to use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any built in screens. The fact that searching for such only brought up user authored libraries make me believe that there aren't any built-in screens you could use.

Some Googling brought up this font selection dialog:

http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/fontpreference-dialog-for-android/

... and a color picker dialog:

http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Comment: Thanks! Sofar I;ve used the color picker and it seems to work great, I'll get on to the fonts later. It was very helpful :)